# How to I use ViewFlipper with images that are on online server/storage?

Tags: java, android

I will be updating pictures everyday online, I need these pictures to auto flip one after another. For example, I will need three images to flip for a particular day, then the following I will put another three different images on athe storage online. So how do I do this? Storage suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know of loading images from drawable folder